# Como fazer uma sequencia datas no python?

Tags: python-3.x, data, pandas

Preciso criar um vetor de datas do **2018-01-01**, **2020-01-11**, sendo que as datas **não** podem ser continuas (eg *2018-01-01*, *2018-01-02*, *2018-01-03*...) e inclua a extremidades.

O mais próximo que consegui foi:

```
import pandas as pd
date_list = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2020-01-11', freq = '3M', closed= 'left')
date_list
Out[3]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-31', '2018-04-30', '2018-07-31', '2018-10-31',
           '2019-01-31', '2019-04-30', '2019-07-31', '2019-10-31'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='3M')
```

Entretanto ele não incluí as extremidades (**2018-01-01**, **2020-01-11**).

Comment: Se elas não devem estar em sequência, como elas devem estar? Qual é a sequência completa que você deseja obter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Márcio, veja se é isso que precisa.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime


dRan = pd.date_range(start ='2018-01-01', 

       end ='2020-01-11', periods = 13)   

res = dRan.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

print(res)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O parâmetro "M" considera sempre o Last Index para o retorno. Tente adaptar o "period" para seu projeto. Qualquer dúvida estamos aqui.